# Application Insights: How to filter only errors

Tags: azure-application-insights

Application Insights distinguishes multiple event types, some of which can potentially represent an error:

- Traces have a verbosity level and those above warning or error represent error conditions
- Requests have a status code and those equal to or above 400 represent error conditions
- Exceptions are always errors.

Now you'd think I can easily filter the search view to show me only all those events representing an error condition, but I can't figure out how.

Do I really need to use the Analytics query stuff to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To look at errors within the Azure Portal, the best way to get the pre-filtered view you're looking for is to use the **Failures** blade rather than **Search**:
[image: Application Insights Failures Blade]

This view shows requests with status codes indicating failure, dependencies indicating failures, and exceptions - in addition to additional filtering tools curated for investigating error scenarios.

Traces aren't covered here, but will be available when you drill down from the Failures blade to a representative transaction:

[image: Application Insights Transaction Details Blade]